# IEnumerable<string> to Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, ienumerable

I suppose that this question might partially duplicate other similar questions, but i'm having troubles with such a situation:

I want to extract from some string sentences

For example from

```
`string sentence = "We can store these chars in separate variables. We can also test against other string characters.";`
```

I want to build an IEnumerable words;

```
var separators = new[] {',', ' ', '.'};

IEnumerable<string> words = sentence.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

After that, go throught all these `words` and take firs character into a distinct ascending ordered collection of characters.

```
var firstChars = words.Select(x => x.ToCharArray().First()).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct();
```

After that, go through both collections and for each character in `firstChars` get all `items` from `words` which has the `first character` equal with `current character` and create a `Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>> dictionary`.

I'm doing this way:

```
var dictionary = (from k in firstChars
                  from v in words
                  where v.ToCharArray().First().Equals(k)
                  select new { k, v })
                  .ToDictionary(x => x);
```

and here is the problem: `An item with the same key has already been added.`
Whis is because into that dictionary It is going to add an existing character.

I included a `GroupBy` extension into my query

```
var dictionary = (from k in firstChars
                  from v in words
                  where v.ToCharArray().First().Equals(k)
                  select new { k, v })
                  .GroupBy(x => x)
                  .ToDictionary(x => x);
```

The solution above gives makes all OK, but it gives me other type than I need.

[image] 
**What I should do to get as result an** `Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>dictionary` **but not** `Dictionary<IGouping<'a,'a>>` ?

The result which I want is as in the bellow image:
[image]
But here I have to iterate with 2 foreach(s) which will Show me wat i want... I cannot understand well how this happens ...

Any suggestion and advice will be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you write `x.ToCharArray().First()` instead of `x[0]`? And why would you use `Equals()` instead of `==`?

Comment: @svic, this is a trivial decision `x.ToCharArray().First()` or `x[0]` :) `Equals()`  instead of `==` also has a unimportant relevance. The big problem is that I need as result an `Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>` . All responses redirect me from `Dictionary` to `ILookup`. I tried to make something according to boy's proposals, but it seems that i still encounter problems. I don't need to print result on console, but to send that dictionary to another receiver which requires `Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>` at the input :)

Comment: One thing I realized: you're asking for the characters in ascending order in a `Dictionary`. Except that is not possible, `Dictionary` doesn't have any order on its keys.

Comment: @svick, ok, they cannot be ordered, i'll be able to order them later into other context

Comment: And the first part of p.s.w.g.'s answer gives you a good way to do this using a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @svick, right! I'm following his solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var words = ...
var dictionary = words.GroupBy(w => w[0])
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.AsEnumerable());
```

But for matter, why not use an [`ILookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx)?

```
var lookup = words.ToLookup(w => w[0]);
```

Comment: I agree with first part of answer, thanks. The needed result is a Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>> but not an ILookup, because I'll send that dictionary to another receiver which requires Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>> at the input :)

Comment: @meorfi Fair enough. I think if your receiver doesn't *need* to add / remove items from the dictionary, it should probably be refactored to use the simpler interface, but whatever works :) -- happy coding.

Comment: I'll think about refactoring also. Thanks you for suggestion

Answer (score 3):

As the relation is one to many, you can use a lookup instead of a dictionary:

```
var lookup = words.ToLookup(word => word[0]);

loopkup['s'] -> store, separate... as an IEnumerable<string>
```

And if you want to display the key/values sorted by first char:

```
for (var sortedEntry in lookup.OrderBy(entry => entry.Key))
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("First letter: {0}", sortedEntry.Key);
  foreach (string word in sortedEntry)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(word);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a better idea than my suggestion. +1